# Custom CSS/Styles in Here Map for InfoBubble

Tags: here-api

I'm using Info Bubble in HereMap, which brings up a popup when the Marker is clicked. In this popup, I'm using custom CSS classes including bootstrap classes to match to the UI requirements.

When I click the marker, the custom styles are not being applied to the popup and its shows a scattered popup.

I'm not able to find any examples that shows a popup in HereMap having rich UI with CSS.

Can anyone of you help me on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are likely to get help more quickly if you include some of your CSS code in your question.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to override the CSS for an `InfoBubble` like this:

```
.H_ib_body {
    width: 275px;
}
```

Of course your CSS could be more complex than mine, but you'll want to look at `.H_ib_body`. Does that accomplish what you're looking for?

Best,